# How to add whereIn in a StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I currently loop through a list of lists to get users who are interested in an event. I have it set in `initState` but when adding or removing an id from the `Firestore` document, the changes are not reflected in the UI. I don't want to update the lists manually. Is there a way to move this code from `initState` to a `StreamBuilder`?

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final interestedUsers = widget.content.interested;

    var chunks = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < interestedUsers.length; i += 10) {
      chunks.add(interestedUsers.sublist(i,
          i + 10 > interestedUsers.length ? interestedUsers.length : i + 10));
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < chunks.length; i++) {
      final snapshot = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .where('uid', whereIn: chunks[i])
          .snapshots();

      snapshot.forEach((element) {
        element.docs.forEach((element) {
          final userElement = UserModel.fromFirestore(element);
          setState(() {
            interested.add(userElement);
          });
        });
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write it like here...this is a full example that handles the loading and empty state to:

```
StreamBuilder(
          stream: _firestore
              .collection('users')
          .where('uid', whereIn: chunks[i])
          .snapshots(),
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {

            //Shows loading indicator
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator( ),
              );
            }

            List<UserNotificationListTile> items = [];
            unredNotifications = [];

            List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> groups = snapshot.data.docs;

            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot g in groups) {
              UserNotification userNotification =
                  new UserNotification.fromSnapshot(g);
              items.add(
                UserNotificationListTile(
                  userNotification: userNotification,
                ),
              );
            }


            //Shows result when there is no data
            if (items.length == 0) {
              return Center(child: NotificationsEmpty());
            }

            return Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 0),
                    children: items.reversed.toList(),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          }),
    );
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try and let you know how it goes.

Comment: So that goes in a loop?

Comment: You put that `StreamBuilder` into the UI as if it is a Widget. The `return` in the `builder` of it will return that as UI Widgets.

Comment: yeah ... but you have `chunks[i]`. Who's `i`? There will be multiple chunks, each containing ten ids.

Comment: If you have nested lists you can put a `StreamBuilder` inside another one. Just return the child one inside the parent one.